# Compare, remove, and count words in Text file

Tags: python-3.x, word-count

I want to compare two text files f1.txt, and f2.txt, remove the common words found in both files from f2.txt and sort the new f2.txt in descending order by frequency

My approach:

1. Make a list of words fro both f1.txt and f2.txt.
2. Remove unwanted characters from the text input.
3. Compare the two list and remove common words from the list generated from f2.txt
4. sorting words in the list generated from f2.txt by frequency

```py
with open(sys.argv[1]) as f1,open(sys.argv[2]) as f2:
    passage = f2.read()
    common = f1.read()
words = re.findall(r'\w+', passage)
common_words = re.findall(r'\w+', common)
passage_text = [words.lower() for words in words]
final = set(passage_text) - set(common_words)
word_count = Counter(final)
for word, count in word_count.items():
    print(word, ":", count)
```

I expect the output to be so thing like:

```
Foo:          12
Bar:          11
Baz:           3
Longword:      1
```

but I am getting the count frequency for every word to be `1`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your value `final` contains only unique words (one for each), that's why the `Counter` shows only 1 occurrence. You need to filter `passage_text` with this set of words and pass that filtered list to Counter:

```
import re
from collections import Counter

passage = '''
    Foo and Bar and Baz or Longword
    Bar or Baz
    Foo foo foo
'''

common = '''and or'''

words = re.findall(r'\w+', passage)
common_words = re.findall(r'\w+', common)
passage_text = [words.lower() for words in words]
final_set = set(passage_text) - set(common_words)
word_count = Counter([w for w in passage_text if w in final_set])
for word, count in sorted(word_count.items(), key=lambda k: -k[1]): # or word_count.most_common()
    print(word, ":", count)
```

Prints:

```
foo : 4
bar : 2
baz : 2
longword : 1
```

Comment: Thanks for the heads up. But how, the result for large text file input isn't in descending order

Comment: @KrysNuvadga I updated the answer. You just need sort the results or use `Counter.most_common()` method.

Answer (score 0):

Here are two ways to count words in a text file.

```
from re import split


def process_line(words, word_dict):
    for word in words:
        if word in word_dict:
            word_dict[word] += 1
        else:
            word_dict[word] = 1


def process_dict(word_dict):
    temp_list = []
    for key, value in word_dict.items():
        temp_list.append((value, key))

    temp_list.sort()
    return temp_list


def format_print(input_list, reverse, word_num):
    if reverse:
        input_list.sort(reverse=True)

    print("\n", ("[Unique Words: " + str(word_num) + "]").center(35, "="))
    print("-"*35 + "\n", "%-16s %s %16s" % ("Word", "|", "Count"), "\n", "-"*35)
    for count, word in input_list:
        print("%-16s %s %16d" % (word, "|", count))


def word_count(_file, max_to_min=False):
    txt = open(_file, "rU")
    word_dict = {}
    for line in txt:
        if line.replace(" ", "") != ("\n" or None):
            process_line(filter(None, split("[^a-zA-Z']+", line.lower())), word_dict)

    txt.close()
    final_list = process_dict(word_dict)
    format_print(final_list, max_to_min, len(word_dict))


word_count("C:\\your_path_here\\Test.txt", True)


#########################################################


from collections import Counter
import re

def openfile(filename):
    fh = open(filename, "r+")
    str = fh.read()
    fh.close()
    return str

def removegarbage(str):
    # Replace one or more non-word (non-alphanumeric) chars with a space
    str = re.sub(r'\W+', ' ', str)
    str = str.lower()
    return str

def getwordbins(words):
    cnt = Counter()
    for word in words:
        cnt[word] += 1
    return cnt

def main(filename, topwords):
    txt = openfile(filename)
    txt = removegarbage(txt)
    words = txt.split(' ')
    bins = getwordbins(words)
    for key, value in bins.most_common(topwords):
        print(key,value)

main('C:\\your_path_here\\Test.txt', 500)
```

Here is a way to compare two text files and retain common elements.

```
with open('C:\\your_path_here\\text1.txt', 'r') as file1:
    with open('C:\\your_path_here\\text2.txt', 'r') as file2:
        same = set(file1).intersection(file2)

same.discard('\n')

with open('C:\\your_path_here\\some_output_file.txt', 'w') as file_out:
    for line in same:
        file_out.write(line)

# For differences, use the code below:
with open('C:\\your_path_here\\text1.txt', 'r') as file1:
    with open('C:\\your_path_here\\text2.txt', 'r') as file2:
        same = set(file1).symmetric_difference(file2)

same.discard('\n')

with open('C:\\your_path_here\\some_output_file.txt', 'w') as file_out:
    for line in same:
        file_out.write(line)
```